# Aggregate summary counts for an array of error objects

Tags: javascript, array, functional-programming, comparative-review, ecmascript-6

I'm doing some refactoring of someone else's code, and just want a second opinion, because of course I *think* my work makes it better, but some validation (or correction) would be helpful.

**Starting with an array like this:**

```
errorLog: [{
 errorCode: 11,
 errorDescription: "abc",
 date: "2017-01-01",
 severity: "H"
},{
 errorCode: 11,
 errorDescription: "abcd",
 date: "2017-01-02",
 severity: "H"
},{
 errorCode: 99,
 errorDescription: "abcd",
 date: "2017-01-02",
 severity: "H"
}]
```

**and trying to get results like this**:

```
errorSummary: [{
 errorCode: 11,
 severity: "H",
 count: 2
},{
 errorCode: 99,
 severity: "H",
 count: 1
}]
```

**this is the existing code**:

```
//instead of this, which is hard to reason about and debug (and includes a line that will never rturn true: if (hardErrorsSorted.includes...)):
let hardErrors = testData.filter(ts1 => ts1.severity === 'H');
let hardErrorsSorted = hardErrors.sort(this.mySorter);
for (let i = 0; i < hardErrorsSorted.length; i++) {
  if (i != hardErrorsSorted.length - 1) {
    if (hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode != hardErrorsSorted[i + 1].errorCode) {
      let errorCount = this.getCount(hardErrorsSorted, hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode);
      this.errorDataList.push({
        errorCode: hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode,
        errorCodeType: 'H',
        errorCodeTotalCount: errorCount
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (hardErrorsSorted.includes(hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode, 0)) {
    } else {
      let errorCount = this.getCount(hardErrorsSorted, hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode);
      this.errorDataList.push({
        errorCode: hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode,
        errorCodeType: 'H',
        errorCodeTotalCount: errorCount
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**and my refactoring:**

```
//use something like this, which is much easier to grasp at a glance, doesn't jump around, and is DRYer
let hardErrorCodes = testData.filter(ts => ts.severity === 'H').map(v => v.errorCode);
let hardErrorCounts = {};

//sum up the unique errors
for (let error of hardErrorCodes) {
  if (!(error in hardErrorCounts)) {
    hardErrorCounts[error] = 0;
  }
  hardErrorCounts[error]++;
}

//add the summed error counts to the master list
for (let error in hardErrorCounts) {
  this.errorDataList.push({
    errorCode: error, 
    errorCodeType: "H", 
    errorCodeTotalCount: hardErrorCounts[error]
  });
```

What do you all think? Is this a helpful refactor, or a waste of time?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another one towards [functional](/questions/tagged/functional) using [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) syntax additions:

```
const predSeverity = severity => err => err.severity == severity
const byCode = (acc, {errorCode: code}) =>
  acc.set(code, (acc.get(code) || 0) + 1)

errorLog.filter(predSeverity("H")).reduce(byCode, new Map())
```

It has a bit different result data format (and type, if only for the receiver-as-return-value of `Map::set`), since the filtering already tells us the severity.

Answer (score 0):

I had [posted first on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47184116/1575353); then [this was the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184317/1575353) given by another user, which I quite like, and whereas mine would need to have more code for `warnings`, this one doesn't:

> You could even go further:

```
const result = [], ids = {};

for(const {errorCode, severity} of hardErrorCodes){
  let uniqueId = errorCode + severity;
  if(ids[uniqueId]){
   ids[uniqueId].count++;
  } else {
  result.push( ids[uniqueId] = { severity, errorCode, count: 1});
 }
}
```

> This makes it 3 times faster (in theory)

Answer (score 0):

The rewritten code definitely feels less cluttered, and it makes sense to remove a block that never gets executed...

There are places where `const` could be used instead of `let` - e.g. for `errorCount` , since it never gets re-assigned. It is advised to default to using `const` and then switch to `let` when re-assignment is deemed necessary. This helps avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

Since the code already uses `.filter()`, more functional approaches like using the [`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) could be used to simplify iterating through the list, unless the performance losses would be too much. Instead of using `filter` and `map`, `reduce` could be used to combine the two approaches - conditionally adding to an output array/object.

```js
function ErrorLog() {
  return {
    testData: [{
      errorCode: 11,
      errorDescription: "abc",
      date: "2017-01-01",
      severity: "H"
    }, {
      errorCode: 11,
      errorDescription: "abcd",
      date: "2017-01-02",
      severity: "H"
    }, {
      errorCode: 99,
      errorDescription: "abcd",
      date: "2017-01-02",
      severity: "H"
    }],
    errorDataList: [],
    getDataList: function() {
      const hardErrorCodes = this.testData.filter(ts => ts.severity === 'H').map(v => v.errorCode);
      const hardErrorCounts = hardErrorCodes.reduce(function(counts, error) {
        counts[error] = counts[error] ? counts[error] + 1 : 1;
        return counts;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(hardErrorCounts).map(function(error) {
        return {
          errorCode: error,
          errorCodeType: "H",
          errorCodeTotalCount: hardErrorCounts[error]
        };
      });
    }
  };
}
const log = ErrorLog();
console.log(log.getDataList());
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of using reduce as well, but didn't nail it down before I came up with my first solution. The downside of this, as with my initial refactoring, is that you have to duplicate most of the code for summing warnings (severity = "W"), whereas the answer above doesn't require that, and only makes one trip through a loop. Curious to know what you think about that one.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner! I support minimizing the number of times data is looped over... which is one reason I would support using `reduce` instead of `filter` and `map` in some cases.